# 3d convolution in c++

Tags: c++, 3d, cuda, convolution

I'm looking for some source code implementing 3d convolution. Ideally, I need C++ code or CUDA code. I'd appreciate if anybody can point me to a nice and fast implementation :-)

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

you understand that convolution is normally done by using an fft?  see, for example, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution

so you need an fft library.

[Fastest method to compute convolution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1548809/fastest-method-to-compute-convolution) suggests http://www.fftw.org/ (for a traditional cpu).

for cuda, use cufft - http://www.gsic.titech.ac.jp/~ccwww/tebiki/tesla_e/tesla6_e.html

Comment: For small kernels it can sometimes be faster to use matrix convolution, in cases where there is hardware to support it (eg, a GPU for 4x4 or 8x8 kernels). For big kernels, Fourier is da man for sure.

Comment: FWIW, the original source for cufft docs is here: http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_develop.html

Answer (score 0):

Are you a registered developer? If so you should download the 3.0 SDK and check out the FDTD3d sample which shows a 3d convolution as applied for an explicit finite differences app. In the 2.3 SDK there was a sample called 3dfd which was similar (and has now been replaced).

It may be more efficient to use this approach rather than FFT if your impulse response is short.

Comment: You can register at http://www.nvidia.com/object/cuda_get.html, click "Apply Now". Alternatively, you can just look at the 3dfd sample in the current SDK, the concepts remain the same.

Answer (score 0):

Intel has a very good example - using SSE + OpenMP and a serial version of it. The code is primarily meant to profile the serial and a parallel approach, but is done in a nice way. http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/16bit-3d-convolution-sse4openmp-implementation-on-penryn-cpu/